# How to extract the layers from the source code in `forward()` function of a PyTorch model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, code-analysis

I want to extract the layers of the model that process the input data as defined in the `forward` function. For example, given the following source code:

```
 def forward(self, inputs): 
     inputs = self.embedding(inputs)
     inputs = F.dropout(inputs, 0.25, self.training)
     return inputs
```

I want to extract the layers that process the input data i.e:

```
input -> embedding -> dropout -> output
```

How do I do this without runing the code?

Answer (score 0):

[`model.children()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.children) will iterate over the submodules (layers) in the network.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear descriptions in the question. Actually, I want to parse the source code to obtain these information instead of runing the code.